# High-pitch, tinny echo in large room

Tags: microphone, echo

I live in a one bedroom flat which is split across floors. Upstairs is my bedroom, and downstairs is my kitchen, living room, bathroom and so forth - the downstairs is conjoined into a single room, which results in it being *approximately* 3m x 10m at its widest point, with the entire room being just over 2m high. The floor within this room is completely tiled. There's furniture in quite a bit of the room, but the area where I am sat is more or less empty except for a leather sofa, my desk, PC and obviously myself.

When I perform any recordings in this room, I obviously get some echo, and it presents itself like a high-pitch, tinny echo. [Here is a sample of the audio on Vocaroo](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1j0N3Ve5KPY). It's minor, but it is incredibly annoying.

I'm currently using the Blue Snowball microphone and it's not really within my budget to get another microphone.

Are there ways I could reduce this echo without breaking the bank? I've seen a tutorial on YouTube for creating a $25 enclosure around the Blue Yeti microphone, but I'm recording in Cardioid and that tutorial seemed to be aiming at eliminating noise omnidirectionally, which the cardioid setting seems to do (from my understanding, anyway).

I'm going to be using the microphone for video narration as well as singing, so reduction in echo would definitely help (especially in the latter case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by buying & installing a reflection shield for the microphone. There was reverb being caused by the walls of my house. Not necessarily due to an infinite loop (or anything to do with the speakers) but simply due to how my walls were situated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the microphone is catching the speakers and making a infinite loop. Because of that you can hear the high note. Try to make speakers quieter or even turn them off. Then look at the recording and see if it is still there.

Comment: I have a noise cancelling headset and no speakers. I'll give it  a go though

Comment: Maybe by studio grade sound absorbers for your walls